# Floating window with a form

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want the edit action of a specific controller to be handled in a window that floats above the main application window (not a new browser window). I can't find anything online that provides info on this, how does one go about doing this. I hope floating window is the correct term for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you'll have to use javascript as it's a client side user interface issue that you're dealing with. try [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) with plugins like [ThickBox](http://jquery.com/demo/thickbox/) to help you load the form onto a modal windows through a floating div

and personally i felt loading the form page in an iframe in the floating div will be an easy solution to what you are trying to achieve

hope this helps =)